# Плавный переход в overflow hidden на прозрачном фоне

Tags: javascript, css

Задача в том, чтобы overflow:hidden не резко обрезал контент, а был плавный переход, учитывая что фон может быть разного цвета (before, after с line-gradient не прокатит). Как можно реализовать такую идею?

Comment: Каво[?](https://i.imgur.com/KXi7Tep.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Задача в именно вашей постановке нерешаема в принципе. Свойство `Overflow` задает способ как должно отображаться содержимое элемента когда оно не умещается в его границы. `Visible` показывает, `scroll`/`auto` прокручивает, `hidden` прячет. Тут вся суть в границе элемента, которая не имеет толщины и, соответственно, не имеет никаких возможностей по управлению отображением. `Overflow:hidden` - это обрезка контента, она либо есть, либо нет, иначе нельзя, как нельзя быть немножко беременной.

Ну а то, что вам надо реализуется полупрозрачными градиентами. Или псевдоэлементы `:before/:after` (непонятно, почему не прокатит, директор запретил?), или наложение другого элемента с градиентом, полупрозрачной картинкой или `box-shadow`.

Comment: Да, line gradient можно поставить, но тогда на фоне он будет выделяться от основного background (картинка). Спасибо за ответ. Буду пробовать.

Comment: ну да, это имеет смысл когда после блока с обрезкой идет равномерный фон...

еще можно попробовать вариант с размытием, но он размоет и нижележащий фон тоже...